Intuition for Penney's coin-flip game
How should I understand intuitively the fact that if I repeatedly flip a fair coin,
(1) the sequence THTH appears before HTHH appears with 9:5 odds, but
(2) the expected numbers of flips it takes for these respective strings to appear are 20 and 18?
That is, in competition, THTH shows up before HTHH; yet in isolation, THTH takes longer to appear!
(This example is given, but not really explained, in Stanley Collings, "Coin sequence probabilities and paradoxes," Bulletin of the Institute of Mathematics and its Applications 18
(1982), 227–232. The intuition for (1) is roughly that immediately after T appears, we see that THTH will be completed before HTHH gets to be completed. The intuition for (2) comes from how 'self-similar' a string is: If you get THTT, you are sent back to the start of trying to form the string THTH, whereas if you get HTHT, you are already at the second letter of HTHH, so not all progress has been lost. This is made precise by an algorithm of Conway — see Collings's paper for details.)
Perhaps it is obvious how to reconcile these observations, but I simply am not able to see it at the moment.


Perhaps consider the following similar "surprise".
Pick a random date, say, "October 12", and look at it on a calendar. Start counting forward days from that date.

The expected number of days until you hit a Thursday is
$$
\frac{1}{7}(0 + 1 + 2 + \ldots 6) = 3
$$
where here I'm counting it as "zero days" if October 12 happens to be a Thursday.

Similarly, the expected number of days until you hit a Friday is 3.

The probability that you hit a thursday before you hit a friday is $\dfrac67$.


So we have two random events (random because we chose the date at random) whose expected "time" is 3, so they occur at equal "distance" from the start on average, but one occurs before the other $\dfrac67$ of the time.
The key thing is that "before-ness" only tells you a tiny bit of data --- it doesn't tell you how LONG before the event it occurs.
Another example of this comes when you consider two peculiar dice: one of them ("the steady one") has a "3" on every face; the other ("the wild one") has a 1 on five faces and a 13 on its sixth face. Both the "wild" and "steady" die roll an average value of 3, but if you roll them together, "steady" beats "wild" five out of six times on average. By adjusting the number 13 up or down a little bit, you can make the expected value of either one be larger, but not change the "five out of six times" winning percentage.
Short summary: 'expected value' isn't as natural a concept as you'd like it to be, and "occurring before" fails to take into account "how much before". This opens up the possibility of apparent paradoxes.

Excellent explanation and example!!

A similar question and answer with a different set up: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198759/which-deck-wins-the-most/4198779#4198779

With the help of John Hughes's answer as well as assistance from a friend, the ideas have clicked for me. I'll answer aspects of my own question directly here.
Situations where THTH appears first are indeed more frequent, but in those worlds, HTHH lags behind only by a little bit (the expected lag is $8$ here). However, worlds in which HTHH appears first are such that THTH lags behind by a decent amount (the expected lag is $20$ here). In this way, the average skews towards THTH appearing later compared to HTHH.
More precisely, define the random variables $X$ and $Y$ to be the numbers of flips it takes for THTH and HTHH respectively to appear. We are interested in understanding the fact that $\mathbf EX>\mathbf EY$. Now this amounts to the positivity of
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf EX-\mathbf EY=\mathbf E(X-Y)\\
&\quad=\mathbf E\bigl(X-Y\mid\text{HTHH}\bigr)\Pr(\text{HTHH})
-\mathbf E\bigl(Y-X\mid\text{THTH}\bigr)\Pr(\text{THTH}),\tag{$*$}
\end{align*}
where $\Pr(\text{HTHH})$ denotes the probability that HTHH appears before THTH appears (and similarly for $\Pr(\text{THTH})$.) It turns out that equation ($*$) becomes $$ 20-18=2=20\cdot{5\over14}-8\cdot{9\over14}$$
when all the numbers are substituted in; this explains our earlier remarks about expected lag.
The first conditional expectation on the right of ($*$) — which gives the expected number of flips to obtain THTH if you start counting right after HTHH has appeared for the first time — is simply equal to $\mathbf EX$, since no prefix of THTH is a suffix of HTHH (so the game has been reset as if it were beginning from scratch). The second conditional expectation is trickier, since the prefixes H and HTH of HTHH are both suffixes of THTH; with some work, one can show that
$$\mathbf E\bigl(Y-X\mid\text{THTH}\bigr)=\sum_{k\ge1}{2k-1\over2^{2k-1}}+\sum_{k\ge1}{2k+\mathbf EY\over 2^{2k}}={10\over9}+{1\over 9}\bigl(8+3\mathbf EY\bigr).$$
Substituting into ($*$) and using fact (1) from the original question, we get
$$\mathbf EX-\mathbf EY={5\over14}\mathbf EX-{9\over14}\biggl({10\over9}+{1\over9}\bigl(8+3\mathbf EY\bigr)\biggr),$$
which simplifies to
$$\mathbf EX-\mathbf EY={2\over9}\bigl(\mathbf EY-9\bigr).$$
It remains for us to show that $\mathbf EY>9$. But the expected number of flips required for any particular length-$k$ string to appear is at least $2^k$ (induct, I think), so we are done.
Note to self: It seems that it is easy to calculate $\mathbf EX$ and $\mathbf EY$, as well as generalizations of such expectations to strings of any length over any fixed alphabet, using absorbing Markov chains, or martingale methods (see exercise 10.6 of David Williams, Probability with Martingales (1991)).

Nice working out of the details! (And I like that last paragraph, too!)

To calculate expectations of this kind, you may also like to see this recursive method.

To see the difference more quickly one can notice that if THTH appears first, there is a 50% that HTHH will occur a single spot later because the first three elements are already there. However, if HTHH appears first, then THTH has to be at least 4 spots later because  it can't overlap with the HTHH.

Perhaps this is related to another paradox, which is even simpler (and maybe more intuitive):

I have two girlfriends, who live in opposite directions from me.  I like them both equally, so each day I go to the road at a random time and take whichever bus turns up first.  Buses come every 10 minutes in each direction.  I expect to visit both girls about equally — but instead I find I'm seeing one four times as often as the other!

(That's from memory — I'm sure I read it somewhere, but a quick search hasn't found it.)
At first it seems impossible, but there's a logical explanation: buses going one way arrive on the hour, 10 past, 20 past, etc.; while buses going the other way arrive at 2 minutes past, 12 past, etc.  This means that in each 10-minute period, there are only 2 minutes when the next bus goes the first way, and for the remaining 8 minutes the next bus goes the other way.  So I'm 4× more likely to go the other way.
As with the question, and other answers, the point here is that there's a correlation between the events.  In each direction, the expected time until the next bus is 5 minutes — but taken together, the buses in the two directions are not independent, so you can't just compare those expectations.
The correlation is harder to see in the other examples, but hopefully this shows how a correlation can mess up your thinking.

This paradox story appears in Martin Gardner’s book “aha!” (and possibly elsewhere)

The intuition here (rather than the precise numbers) should be all about overlaps, where the initial results of one pattern match the final results of itself or of the other pattern.
Any pattern of four results is as likely as any other, so in a long string of results, the expected number of times a given pattern of four results appears (counting overlaps) does not depend on the pattern.

Patterns which overlap themselves a lot are more likely to be clumply than those that which only overlap a little or not at all; the higher expectation of the number of flips until the first appearance of a high-overlap offsets this.
Consider looking for the low-self-overlap HHHT in $19$ flips where you expect it to appear once, but it could appear $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$ times; contrast this with the high-self-overlap HHHH which you also expect it to appear once, but it could appear from $0$ up to $16$ times, and to keep the same expectation it needs a higher probability of appearing $0$ times than HHHT.  Similar things happen for other number of flips.  This is what leads HHHH to have an expected time of first appearance $(30)$ almost double that of HHHT of $(16)$.
Your THTH and HTHH are less extreme than either of these but THTH has more self-overlap (TH) than HTHH (H) and so more likely to be clumpy and thus has a higher expected time of first appearance.

A race between two patterns (Penney's game) combines the previous effect with a different one, namely that of one pattern overlapping the other.

Going back to the HHHH and HHHT example, in a long string of results about half of the HHHT patterns will immediately follow and overlap with a HHHH pattern because the start of HHHT is the same as the end of HHHH (HHH).  This manages to exactly offset the clumpiness of HHHH so both are equally likely to arrive first in a race.
With other patterns there is no reason to expect this to be exact, and they could even reinforce rather than offset.
Compare HHHH with THHH where the two self-overlap and cross-overlap effects reinforce.  Except for the first four flips, HHHH must either follow itself or THHH, both of which are too late to win, and so HHHH must lose the race unless it wins immediately.
Your example, where the start of HTHH overlaps with the end of THTH (both HTH and just H) but not the other way round, illustrates how in a race the large cross-overlap effect benefitting THTH can more than offset the small self-overlap effect benefitting HTHH.

